# Расположение пунктов списка

Tags: html, css

В верстке есть два меню, пункты в каждом расположены в два столбца
[image]

для пунктов списка заданы

```
.sideBox ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

но получается, что элементы списка выстраиваются в таком порядке

пункт1 пункт2
пункт3 пункт4
пункт5 пункт6
и тд.

а не

пункт1 пункт4
пункт2 пункт5
пункт3 пункт6

на месяцах особенно заметно [Ссылка на верстку](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index5/index.html)
Можно как-то поправить чтобы все задавалось в правильном порядке?

И еще по этому же меню вопрос, в ие 7 не получается сделать отображение в два столбца, получается один столбец. Как сделать так, чтобы в ие7 было два столбца?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [Многоколоночный текст на CSS3](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/content/css3-multi-column.html)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы списки были в два столбца как в IE7, так и в других браузерах, используйте `float: left; display: block;` вместо `display: inline-block`:

```
.sideBox ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Также после каждого списка вставьте div:

```
...
</ul>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
...
```

С порядком сложнее, думаю при помощи CSS проблему не решить.., придется заранее формировать списки с определенным порядком элементов.